# Sumar Count con condiciones

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta que cuenta la cantidad de tickets  `[count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)]` que existen por tópicos  `[ost_help_topic.topic_id]`. Estos tópicos los tuve que agrupar (que fue un requerimiento) y, además, tengo que sumar la cantidad de tickets por cada grupo de tópicos.

Los tópicos ya los tengo agrupados y a cada grupo también le asigne un *id* `[topic_id_alias]`.

Lo que no he podido lograr es sumar la cantidad de tickets de los grupos correspondientes.

Por Ejemplo:

```
WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN "Agenda Médica(Caso - V.2)" .
```

`ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24` tiene su propia cantidad de tickets `[count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)]` y `ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25` también, pero como ahora están agrupados necesito sumar el `count` de ese grupo y así con el resto de los grupos.

En la imagen se muestra los valores de ahora pero necesito arreglar la consulta de tal forma de poder sumar `0 + 12` (por ejemplo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                                count(ost_ticket.ticket_id) as cuenta,ost_help_topic.topic_id ,
                                CASE
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN "Agenda Médica(Caso - V.2)"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 35 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 29 THEN "Stock y Recetas"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 20 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 85 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 83 THEN "Administrativos"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 71 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 79 THEN "RCE - RCO"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 63 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 33 THEN "Tele"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 30 THEN "Urgencia"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 72 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 28 THEN "Reportería y DataWH"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 21 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 75 THEN "Manager"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 27 THEN "Interconsulta"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 34 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 46 THEN "Archivos (Fichas)"
                                END 
                                AS topic,
                                CASE
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN 1
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 35 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 29 THEN 2
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 20 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 85 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 83 THEN 3
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 71 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 79 THEN 4
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 63 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 33 THEN 5
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 30 THEN 6
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 72 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 28 THEN 7
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 21 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 75 THEN 8
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 27 THEN 9
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 34 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 46 THEN 10
                                END as topic_id_alias

                                FROM
                                ost_ticket
                                right OUTER JOIN ost_help_topic ON ost_ticket.topic_id = ost_help_topic.topic_id 
                                AND ost_help_topic.dept_id = 10 AND ost_ticket.status_id = 1                                                    
                                GROUP BY
                                topic
                                ORDER BY
                                topic asc
```

Comment: Leí tu descripción un par de veces y no comprendo lo que quieres lograr. Sugiero que incluyas un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas obtener con esos datos. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola ! edite la descripción espero este mas claro y me puedan echar una mano . Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero hacer un `select from select`<sup>1</sup>

La idea general es que puedes utilizar el resultado de un `select` como si fuese una tabla en tu cláusula `from` para realizar operaciones adicionales.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso, podría ser algo como esto:

```
select q1.topic_id_alias, min(q1.topic) topic, sum(q1.cuenta) cuenta_total
  from (SELECT DISTINCT count(ost_ticket.ticket_id) as cuenta, ost_help_topic.topic_id ,
                                CASE
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN "Agenda Médica(Caso - V.2)"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 35 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 29 THEN "Stock y Recetas"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 20 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 85 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 83 THEN "Administrativos"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 71 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 79 THEN "RCE - RCO"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 63 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 33 THEN "Tele"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 30 THEN "Urgencia"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 72 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 28 THEN "Reportería y DataWH"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 21 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 75 THEN "Manager"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 27 THEN "Interconsulta"
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 34 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 46 THEN "Archivos (Fichas)"
                                END 
                                AS topic,
                                CASE
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN 1
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 35 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 29 THEN 2
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 20 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 85 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 83 THEN 3
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 71 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 79 THEN 4
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 63 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 33 THEN 5
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 30 THEN 6
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 72 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 28 THEN 7
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 21 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 75 THEN 8
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 27 THEN 9
                                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 34 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 46 THEN 10
                                END as topic_id_alias

                                FROM
                                ost_ticket
                                right OUTER JOIN ost_help_topic ON ost_ticket.topic_id = ost_help_topic.topic_id 
                                AND ost_help_topic.dept_id = 10 AND ost_ticket.status_id = 1                                                    
                                GROUP BY
                                topic
          ) as q1
  group by q1.topic_id_alias
  ORDER BY min(topic) asc
```

El `select` dentro del `from` es básicamente la consulta de tu pregunta, sin la cláusula `order by` (que no está soportada en la *tabla al vuelo*), y que he trasladado hacia el final.

Si utilizas MySQL 8.0 o superior, entonces puedes utilizar un CTE, que en mi opinión es más legible y más fácil de mantener:

```
with
q1 as (
SELECT DISTINCT count(ost_ticket.ticket_id) as cuenta, ost_help_topic.topic_id ,
        CASE
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN "Agenda Médica(Caso - V.2)"
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 35 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 29 THEN "Stock y Recetas"
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 20 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 85 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 83 THEN "Administrativos"
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 71 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 79 THEN "RCE - RCO"
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 63 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 33 THEN "Tele"
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 30 THEN "Urgencia"
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 72 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 28 THEN "Reportería y DataWH"
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 21 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 75 THEN "Manager"
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 27 THEN "Interconsulta"
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 34 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 46 THEN "Archivos (Fichas)"
        END 
        AS topic,
        CASE
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN 1
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 35 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 29 THEN 2
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 20 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 85 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 83 THEN 3
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 71 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 79 THEN 4
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 63 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 33 THEN 5
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 30 THEN 6
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 72 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 28 THEN 7
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 21 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 75 THEN 8
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 27 THEN 9
            WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 34 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 46 THEN 10
        END as topic_id_alias

        FROM
        ost_ticket
        right OUTER JOIN ost_help_topic ON ost_ticket.topic_id = ost_help_topic.topic_id 
        AND ost_help_topic.dept_id = 10 AND ost_ticket.status_id = 1                                                    
        GROUP BY
        topic
)
select q1.topic_id_alias, min(q1.topic) topic, sum(q1.cuenta) cuenta_total
  from q1
  group by q1.topic_id_alias
  ORDER BY min(topic) asc
```

Nuevamente, el query al interior del CTE es el mismo de tu pregunta, sin la cláusula `order by`.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Mi solución *natural* sería utilizar un CTE, pero MySQL los soporta solo a partir de la versión 8 y no estoy seguro de qué versión es la que utilizas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda , efectivamente la solución era anidar un select y hacer el order by correspondiente . Muchas gracias !!

Comment: @JorgeObreque Te sugiero entonces que le pongas su respectiva palomita a la respuesta de jachguate

Comment: @AlvaroC. listo amigo :D

Answer (score 0):

Logre Solucionarlo , lo dejaré aquí quizás a alguien le sirva mas adelante

```
    SELECT sum(cantidad) total,topic_id_f,
CASE
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN "Agenda Médica(Caso - V.2)"
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 35 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 29 THEN "Stock y Recetas"
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 20 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 85 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 83 THEN "Administrativos"
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 71 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 79 THEN "RCE - RCO"
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 63 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 33 THEN "Tele"
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 30 THEN "Urgencia"
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 72 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 28 THEN "Reportería y DataWH"
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 21 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 75 THEN "Manager"
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 27 THEN "Interconsulta"
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 34 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 46 THEN "Archivos (Fichas)"
END 
AS topic,
CASE
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN 1
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 35 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 29 THEN 2
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 20 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 85 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 83 THEN 3
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 71 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 79 THEN 4
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 63 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 33 THEN 5
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 30 THEN 6
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 72 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 28 THEN 7
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 21 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 75 THEN 8
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 27 THEN 9
        WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 34 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 46 THEN 10
END as topic_id_alias 


FROM (SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 24 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 25 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 35 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 29 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 20 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 85 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 83 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 71 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 79 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 63 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 33 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 30 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 72 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 28 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 21 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 75 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 27 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)
                    WHEN ost_help_topic.topic_id = 34 || ost_help_topic.topic_id = 46 THEN Count(ost_ticket.ticket_id)



                END
                as cantidad,
                ost_help_topic.topic,
                ost_help_topic.topic_id as topic_id_f
                FROM
                ost_ticket
                right OUTER JOIN ost_help_topic ON ost_ticket.topic_id = ost_help_topic.topic_id 
                AND ost_help_topic.dept_id = 10 AND ost_ticket.status_id = 1
                GROUP BY
                ost_help_topic.topic
                ORDER BY
                ost_help_topic.topic asc) as A 
                INNER JOIN ost_help_topic ON A.topic_id_f = ost_help_topic.topic_id
                GROUP BY topic
                ORDER BY topic_id_alias
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor añade una explicación de lo que hiciste para solucionar tu código